# Get jupyter notebook to print a whole function that it has imported

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I had a python function saved in a .py file but I just accidentally wrote over it.

However, I have a jupyter notebook open and loaded with the function before I erased it (so I guess it is using the .pyc ?). So at the beginning of my notebook:

`from now_deleted_script import deleted_function`

Is it possible for me to tell the jupyter notebook to print out the whole `deleted_function` that it has stored in its memory?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use `%ed deleted_function` to see the original source code.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate please? I'm not clear what you mean.

Comment: Unfortunately, no editor opened up. I think because I'm using a remote machine perhaps.

Comment: I think this might help you: https://gist.github.com/simonw/8aa492e59265c1a021f5c5618f9e6b12